# Parameter pack expansion doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters

I tried to make multiplex of `std::set`, named `NDos::set_multiplex`, which can view the elements in perspective of various comparison objects. For example, a set of playing cards could be sorted with rank first and suit second, or suit first and rank second; `NDos::set_multiplex` enables to do this conveniently.
`NDos::set_multiplex` does this by inheriting multiple `std::set`s, one storing the elements, and the others storing the iterator to the elements.
`NDos::IterComp` is a `Callable` type that compares the elements refered by two iterators.

Here is the code:

```
/*...*/
namespace NDos {
    template <class T, class Comp0, class... Comps> class set_multiplex :
        private std::set<T, Comp0>,
        private std::set<
            typename std::set<T, Comp0>::iterator,
            IterComp<typename std::set<T, Comp0>::iterator, Comps>
        >... {
    private:
        typedef std::set<T, Comp0> Base0;
    public:
        /*...*/
        using typename Base0::iterator;
        using typename Base0::const_iterator;
        using typename Base0::reverse_iterator;
        using typename Base0::const_reverse_iterator;
#define Bases std::set<iterator, IterComp<iterator, Comps>>
        /*constructors*/
        // copy constructor : default
        // move constructor : default
        // copy assignment operator : default
        // move assignment operator : default
        // destructor : default
        /*...*/
        void clear() noexcept {
            Base0::clear();
            Bases::clear()...;
        }
        iterator insert(const T &value) {
            return emplace(value);
        }
        iterator insert(T &&value) {
            return emplace(std::move(value));
        }
        iterator insert(const_iterator pos, const T &value) {
            return emplace_hint(pos, value);
        }
        iterator insert(const_iterator pos, T &&value) {
            return emplace_hint(pos, std::move(value));
        }
        template <class InputIt> void insert(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
            while (first != last)
                insert(*first++);
        }
        void insert(std::initializer_list<T> ilist) {
            insert(std::make_move_iterator(ilist.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(ilist.end()));
        }
        template <class... Args> iterator emplace(Args &&...args) {
            iterator i0 = Base0::emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...).first;
            Bases::insert(i0)...;
            return i0;
        }
        template <class... Args> iterator emplace_hint(const_iterator pos, Args &&...args) {
            iterator i0 = Base0::emplace_hint(pos, std::forward<Args>(args)...).first;
            Bases::insert(i0)...;
            return i0;
        }
        iterator erase(iterator pos) {
            Bases::erase(pos)...;
            return Base0::erase(pos);
        }
        iterator erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last) {
            while (first != last)
                erase(first++);
        }
        size_type erase(const T &key) {
            iterator pos = find(key);
            if (pos == end())
                return 0;
            else {
                erase(pos);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        void swap(set_multiplex &other) noexcept {
            Base0::swap(other);
            Bases::swap(other)...;
        }
        /*...*/
#undef Bases
    };
}
```

The parameter packs aren't expanded properly. G++ 6.2 reports those errors each expansion: (In function `clear`, `emplace`, `emplace_hint`, `erase`, and `swap`)

```
error: expected ';' before '...' token
error: parameter packs not expanded with '...'
```

Why do these happen?

Comment: Please post more complete compiler output. There will be a line number somewhere (and show us which line that is). Also try to reduce your code to the critical part.

Comment: @Christoph OK, I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 you can't simply do this:

```
Bases::clear()...;
```

The same happens for all the other places where you have used `...` in that way:

```
Bases::insert(i0)...;
Bases::erase(pos)...;
Bases::swap(other)...;
```

Try to use something like this:

```
void clear() noexcept {
    Base0::clear();
    int _[] = { 0, (Bases::clear(), 0)... };
    (void)_; // silent warnings, nothing more
}
```

That is a common trick used around while waiting for C++17 and its fold expressions.

---

A particular mention for `swap` function: if you swap `other` with `Base0`, `other` theoretically will contain data in `Base0` after the swap. Using it once more for another swap doesn't seem to be a good idea.
Maybe you should review the implementation of your `swap` function.

Comment: During `Base0::swap(other)`, no elements are copied or moved, and all iterators remain valid. So this has no problem.